# REST: accessing members of a collection through multiple ids

Tags: api, rest, servicestack

I have a REST service handling video servers on a network.

Each video server can be identified in several ways: by its serial number,
by its name, or by its machine number.

For returning a collection of all servers available on my network, things
are pretty much simple: I have defined the following route:

```
[Route("/servers", "GET")]
```

and the following request class:

```
public class ServerCollection : IReturn<List<ServerDto>>
{
    ...
}
```

Now, I'd like to return a specific server from my collection, identifying
it either by its serial number, by its machine name, or its machine number.

For doing so, I have defined the following routes:

```
[Route("/servers/{SerialNumber}", "GET")]
[Route("/servers/machinenumbers/{MachineNumber}", "GET")]
[Route("/servers/machinenames/{MachineName}", "GET")]
```

and the following request class:

```
public class Server : IReturn<ServerDto>
{
    public uint SerialNumber { get; set; }
    public uint MachineNumber { get; set; }
    public string MachineName { get; set; }
}
```

So, I can access my server collection through:

```
GET /servers
```

and get a specific server using either:

```
GET /servers/3
GET /servers/machinenumbers/42
GET /servers/machinenames/supercalifragilisticexpialidocious
```

Is that the right way to proceed? I have the feeling that this is not very
RESTful. Should I consider this as a search in my collection instead of using "artificial"
resources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would represent the service in one way that is always unique (serial-number may be correct).

For the query I would do something like `/servers/?name=[name]` or `/server/?id=[id]` or just `/servers/[serial]` (if you want to use the serial number directly). When requesting the name or id you should change the url in the request to `servers/[serial]` to keep the url unique.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is the ServiceStack-way. Just make both `uint` field nullable so in the service implementation you're sure what parameter search by.

Answer (score 1):

That's fine, as long as you redirect (3xx) two of the URI's to the other, instead of returning the same representation (2xx) at all three. Otherwise, you're going to have a heck of a time keeping the copies in sync within a cache. In your case, it seems logical to have the machinenumbers and machinenames resources redirect to the servers/{id} resources.

If anything, it's generic search using k=v parameters that's antithetical to REST. Remember that URI's identify resources, and querystrings are part of the URI: different querystrings identify different resources. Since the set of terms in a form-style querystring is typically large (in the interest of convenience), and the terms can appear in any order, this causes an explosion of potential resources (if you're not planning on relying on caching for efficiency, then you have lots of other options, but that's not REST).